# GameObject keeps snapping to camera size on play

Tags: unity, c#, camera, transformation

I'm in the process of making my GameObject move when I drag it across the screen using touch. But my current issue is when I press play to test the game, game object snaps to the size of my camera on the Y. The camera by default is set to a size of "5" but I have mine set to "5.194104". The GameObject will snap to this position on play. I cannot figure out why. Instead of the object staying at the -4.5f like I have in the Vector3, it jumps to the camera size.

Here is what I have:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class PaddlePosition : MonoBehaviour
{
     void Update()
     {
         OnFingerDrag();
     }

     private void OnFingerDrag()
     {
           Vector3 fingerPosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, -4.5f, 0.0f);
           Vector3 objectPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(fingerPosition);

           transform.position = objectPosition;
     }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show an image of what the gameobject is doing?

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen to position your object at a depth of 0.0f world units from the camera? That seems unlikely to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the -4.5f to be set to the object position, not the finger position. i.e. `objectPosition.y = -4.5f`.

The finger/mouse position is in screen space where `(0,0)` is the bottom-left corner of the screen and the right-top is `(pixelWidth,pixelHeight)`. A negative y value (-4.5f) will just result in the center of the object being clamped to 4.5 pixels off screen at the bottom of the screen.

Your code should look something like this:

```
private void OnFingerDrag()
{
    Vector3 objectPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    objectPosition.y = -4.5f;

    transform.position = objectPosition;
}
```